# next intent stop my app retrofit 2 and pass profile data next intent

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Resul>() { 
    @Override 
    public void onResponse(Call<Resul> call, Response<Resul> response) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Log.d("response", "code = " + response.code());

    Log.d("mvvvv","StudentId  :  "+response.body().toString());
    String h=response.body().toString();
    if("1".equals(h)){        
        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," user name not valid  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Pojo class

```
package com.example.admin.myappl.Interface;

public class Resul {
    private User_info user_info;

    private Response Response;

    public User_info getUser_info ()
    {
        return user_info;
    }

    public void setUser_info (User_info user_info)
    {
        this.user_info = user_info;
    }

    public Response getResponse ()
    {
        return Response;
    }

    public void setResponse (Response Response)
    {
        this.Response = Response;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return ""+Response+"";
    }

    public class Response
    {
        private String response_message;

        private String response_code;

        public String getResponse_message ()
        {
            return response_message;
        }

        public void setResponse_message (String response_message)
        {
            this.response_message = response_message;
        }

        public String getResponse_code ()
        {
            return response_code;
        }

        public void setResponse_code (String response_code)
        {
            this.response_code = response_code;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return response_code;
        }
    }
    public class User_info
    {
        private String profile_picture;

        private String lastweek_command;

        private String weight;

        private String student_id;

        private String push_notification_status;

        private String id;

        private String first_name;

        private String updated_at;

        private String height;

        private String blood_group;

        private String email;

        private String address;

        private String dob;

        private String last_name;

        private String gender;

        private String general_command;

        private String activity;

        private String mobile_no;

        public String getProfile_picture ()
        {
            return profile_picture;
        }

        public void setProfile_picture (String profile_picture)
        {
            this.profile_picture = profile_picture;
        }

        public String getLastweek_command ()
        {
            return lastweek_command;
        }

        public void setLastweek_command (String lastweek_command)
        {
            this.lastweek_command = lastweek_command;
        }

        public String getWeight ()
        {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight (String weight)
        {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public String getStudent_id ()
        {
            return student_id;
        }

        public void setStudent_id (String student_id)
        {
            this.student_id = student_id;
        }

        public String getPush_notification_status ()
        {
            return push_notification_status;
        }

        public void setPush_notification_status (String push_notification_status)
        {
            this.push_notification_status = push_notification_status;
        }

        public String getId ()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId (String id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirst_name ()
        {
            return first_name;
        }

        public void setFirst_name (String first_name)
        {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }

        public String getUpdated_at ()
        {
            return updated_at;
        }

        public void setUpdated_at (String updated_at)
        {
            this.updated_at = updated_at;
        }

        public String getHeight ()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight (String height)
        {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public String getBlood_group ()
        {
            return blood_group;
        }

        public void setBlood_group (String blood_group)
        {
            this.blood_group = blood_group;
        }

        public String getEmail ()
        {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail (String email)
        {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getAddress ()
        {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress (String address)
        {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getDob ()
        {
            return dob;
        }

        public void setDob (String dob)
        {
            this.dob = dob;
        }

        public String getLast_name ()
        {
            return last_name;
        }

        public void setLast_name (String last_name)
        {
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }

        public String getGender ()
        {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender (String gender)
        {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getGeneral_command ()
        {
            return general_command;
        }

        public void setGeneral_command (String general_command)
        {
            this.general_command = general_command;
        }

        public String getActivity ()
        {
            return activity;
        }

        public void setActivity (String activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public String getMobile_no ()
        {
            return mobile_no;
        }

        public void setMobile_no (String mobile_no)
        {
            this.mobile_no = mobile_no;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "ClassPojo [profile_picture = "+profile_picture+", lastweek_command = "+lastweek_command+", weight = "+weight+", student_id = "+student_id+", push_notification_status = "+push_notification_status+", id = "+id+", first_name = "+first_name+", updated_at = "+updated_at+", height = "+height+", blood_group = "+blood_group+", email = "+email+", address = "+address+", dob = "+dob+", last_name = "+last_name+", gender = "+gender+", general_command = "+general_command+", activity = "+activity+", mobile_no = "+mobile_no+"]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: Elaborate your question in detail so we can understood properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
String h=response.body().toString();
```

Use

```
Resul result = response.body();
```

If condition should be like this

```
if("1".equals(result.getResponse().getResponse_code())
```

Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate pojo class

If you are using `gson` for parsing the `@SerializedName("your_key")` , 
`@Expose` these 2 tags are required. Otherwise those values will be *null*